# Вопрос о типе памяти, в которой находятся члены класса

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, память

При создании массива в стеке

```
int stek_array [1000000];
```

произойдет переполнение стека, программа не скомпилируется, это понимаю.

При создании объекта

```
A* ob2 = new A();
```

ob2 будет находится в куче.

Вопрос следующий:

1. В каком типе памяти, стек или куча, будет тогда находится ob2.m? Ведь программа скомпилируется.
2. Раз программа скомилировалась, по идее ob.m будет находится в куче. В стеке массиву не хватило бы памяти. Но, это ведь тогда противоречит синтаксису определения массива в куче без оператора new.
3. Если все же ob.m находится в куче, надо ли в деструктор класса добавлять удаление массива?

   delete m;
4. Есть ли в с++ или visual studio средства посмотреть тип памяти, в которой находится та или иная переменная?
5. Если создам объект в стеке A ob, а у класса "A" будет член int m [1000000]. В какой памяти тогда будет m? Ведь в стеке места ему не хватит

Код:

```
class A {
public:
    int m[10000000];

    A(){};
    ~A(){};
};

int main () {
    int stek_array [1000000];               массив в стеке -> переполнение стека -> крах программы
    int *heap_array = new int[1000000]; массив в куче, памяти хватает
    delete heap_array;                  удалили массив из кучи
    A ob;                                   ob и ob.m в стеке -> переполнение стека -> крах программы

    A* ob = new A();                        вопрос касается этой строчки
    delete ob;                          

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. В куче - раз выделение памяти для объекта в куче, а массив - просто его часть.
2. *Но, это ведь тогда противоречит синтаксису определения массива в куче без оператора new.*
   Почему? массив является частью объекта, который находится в куче, как единое целое. Посмотрите, чему равно `sizeof(A)`. Вот эта память и выделяется для объекта - в данном случае она включает массив.
3. Нет, потому что это удаление выполняется автоматически - при удалении объекта. Вот если бы у вас был член `int*m;` и в конструкторе для него выделялась бы память - тогда да, в деструкторе ее нужно было бы освобождать. Здесь же *отдельного* выделения памяти для массива нет.
4. Да по сути и так видно, что где :) Наверное, можно - по адресам или еще как-то...
   Но я даже не могу представить ситуацию, когда объект выделен в куче, а какая-то его часть - в стеке (кроме извращения типа передаче указателя памяти, выделенной в стеке...).

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Тогда еще вопрос. Если создам объект в стеке A ob, а у класса "A" будет член int m [1000000]. В какой памяти тогда будет m? Ведь в стеке места ему не хватит.

Comment: @pucher "Ведь в стеке места ему не хватит." - тогда ни в какой.

Comment: Вы не сможете создать такой объект - тут либо все, либо ничего. Вы не можете создать объект, половина членов которого будет в стеке, а половина - в куче, например...

Comment: @Harry, и для закрепления понимания. Если создам объект в стеке A ob, а у класса "A" будет член int m = new int [1000000], все равно попытается запихнуть весь объект в стек и потерпит неудачу?

Comment: @pucher: Что такое "член int m = new int [1000000],"? Это бессмысленный синтаксис. И почему вы решили, что язык С++ будет пытаться запихнуть это в стек, если вы явно использовали new-expression для создания объекта именно в динамической памяти?

Comment: Думаю, вы имеете в виду `int * m`. Нет, в данном случае в стеке будет находиться член `m` как неотъемлемая часть объекта. Размером в указатель. А куда он указывает - выделяется через `new` в куче. И в этом случае - если вы не передаете владение etc etc - эту память нужно освобождать (ну, если только ваш проект не предусматривает утечку памяти или еще какие-то особенности).

Answer (score 3):

Механизм имеет много агрегатов.   По вашему где находятся эти агрегаты, если механизм находится на Луне? Наверняка они, как часть механизма, вместе с ним на Луне. После уничтожения механизма, его агрегаты уничтожатся...

Если вы хотите выразить другое отношение, для этого существуют ассоциативность и наследование.  Например, этот механизм может иметь и  инструкцию, но инструкция вполне может находится не вместе с ним на Луне, а на Земле... Такое отношение(ассоциативность) выражать можно так.

```
class Mechanism {
    Mechanism() : m(nullptr) {}
    //...
private:
    direction* m;
};
```

Если указатель нулевой, то нет инструкции. Если он указывает на инструкцию, находящийся в обьекте Земля, то независимо от того, где находится механизм, инструкция будет находится там, где находится Земля

Answer (score 3):

1. В языке С++ нет такого понятия как "тип памяти". В С++ есть такое понятие, как "продолжительность хранения" (storage duration), которое говорит, как долго будет существовать память объекта, будет ли она освобождена автоматически и если будет, то когда.

   В данном случае гарантируется, что память массива `A::m` будет существовать ровно столько, сколько существует память охватывающего его объекта типа `A`. Это фактически все, что вас должно беспокоить.

   Практически же ваш массив является неотделимой встроенной частью объекта типа `A`. Где расположен объект типа `A`, там же расположен и массив `A::m`.
2. В С++ нет такого понятия, как "синтаксис определения массива в куче". Невозможно *определить* что-то в куче. Определение можно предоставить только для *именованного* объекта, а объекты в куче не имеют имен. Объекты в куче создаются специальными *выражениями* (например, *new-выражение*), а не *определениями*.

   При этом объявление нестатического члена класса не является *определением* вообще. Поэтому бессмысленно пытаться судить по этому объявлению о том, как и где будет выделяться память для объекта.
3. Нет, не надо. Вы не выполняли *new-выражение*, чтобы выделить память индивидуально для этого массива? Значит вам не нужно выполнять и *delete-выражение* для ее освобождения.
4. Ну наверное взглянув на адрес объекта и посмотрев на карту адресного пространства процесса можно определить, где именно располагается объект. Да, для всего этого существуют системно-зависимые и реализационно-зависимые средства.
5. Если "не хватит", значит вы и не сможете его создать. Вы же сами уже пришли к такому выводу в ходе своих экспериментов.

Comment: Просто не тип памяти, а место в памяти.  Именно от этого места зависит (но не только)продолжительность хранения. Продолжительность хранения  это не понятие, а   свойство